# Retrieving Arrays from Parse and save them in a Dictionary with a corresponding value. [String(): [String]()]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I am a beginner here and I'm getting problem in retrieving arrays from parse..
My problem is as follows..

I've made a class called "TypeOfNumbers"

```
var typeOfNumbers:PFObject = PFObject(className: "TypeOfNumbers")
    typeOfNumbers["type"] = "Prime"
    typeOfNumbers["numbers"] = ["2", "3", "5", "7", "11", "13"]
    typeOfNumbers.saveInBackground()
```

now let say we have another row in "TypeOfNumbers" class as follows:

```
var typeOfNumbers:PFObject = PFObject(className: "TypeOfNumbers")
    typeOfNumbers["type"] = "Squares
    typeOfNumbers["numbers"] = ["1", "4", "9", "16", "25"]
    typeOfNumbers.saveInBackground()
```

now i want to retrieve these two arrays with their corresponding type also..

let say i want to retrieve these arrays and want to save in a dictionary like:

[Prime: ["2", "3", "5", "7", "11", "13"], Squares: ["2", "3", "5", "7", "11", "13"]]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to write this code:

```
var dictionary = [String:String]
var number = 0
let typeOfNumbersAsArrayOfStrings = typeOfNumbers["numbers"] as! [String]
let typeOfNumbersAsArrayOfStrings2 = typeOfNumbers["numbers"] as! [String]
for object in typeOfNumbersAsArrayOfStrings {
     dictionary["\(object)"] = typeOfNumbersAsArrayOfStrings2[number]
     ++number
}
```

Comment: I dint get this properly, how am i going to retrieve this data from parse if i have many "Types" . I mean in this example i've considered just two types of numbers.. What if there are many types of numbers containing the arrays of numbers?? Could you please explain it properly?? I am stuck here from a week ago now.. :/